# Add log4j to eclipse project

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, log4j

I have Eclipse running on my Ubuntu and workspace in ~/Workspace directory. I have log4j downloaded and extracted in my workspace.  Under `~/workspace/apache-log4j-1.2.17$` I have `log4j-1.2.17.jar` file. I was trying to tell `Eclipse` to use `log4j`by setting `project properties -> libraries -> Add external jar`. Unfortunately my main class does not sees log4j. What I do wrong?

Where is right place for jar files in linux?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?

Comment: try moving the jar into the project in a seperate folder (e.g. "jar") and go to properties -> libraries -> add jar (NOT extenal). Also, check the jar isnt supposed to come with a native.

Comment: This helped. But why is idea of external jar then? And do I always need copy log4j jar to each project?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using Maven to manage its dependencies. For well facilitate their work.

Just add the dependency in your pom.xml file of the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Example of package structure and where the file must be log4j.properties:

[image]

Example of log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I hope this helps!